# Transferring each column to one worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

So as the title says, I wish to use VBA code to have each column in a worksheet to be transferred to their respective new worksheets. For example:

ColumnA:

1. Row1: House1
2. Row2: Sam
3. Row3: Pippin
4. Row4: Luke

ColumnB:

1. Row1: House2
2. Row2: Adam
3. Row3: Albert
4. Row4: Albus

Then after running the VBA, there will be added two new worksheets named ColumnA and ColumnB with their respective data, in the same way it is.

I have found a code somewhere that does something similar - instead of transferring columns, it's transferring group of rows of data to new worksheets. Here is the original code, and it works fine:

```
Sub parse_data()
    Dim lr As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim vcol, i As Integer
    Dim icol As Long
    Dim myarr As Variant
    Dim title As String
    Dim titlerow As Integer

    vcol = 1
    Set ws = Sheets("109 (2)")
    lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, vcol).End(xlUp).Row
    title = "A1:C1"
    titlerow = ws.Range(title).Cells(1).Row
    icol = ws.Columns.Count
    ws.Cells(1, icol) = "Unique"

    For i = 2 To lr
        On Error Resume Next
        If ws.Cells(i, vcol) <> "" And Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ws.Cells(i,     vcol), ws.Columns(icol), 0) = 0 Then
            ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, icol).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = ws.Cells(i, vcol)
        End If
    Next

    myarr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ws.Columns(icol).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants))
    ws.Columns(icol).Clear

    For i = 2 To UBound(myarr)
        ws.Range(title).AutoFilter field:=vcol, Criteria1:=myarr(i) & ""
        If Not Evaluate("=ISREF('" & myarr(i) & "'!A1)") Then
            Sheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = myarr(i) & ""
        Else
            Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Move after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
        End If

        ws.Range("A" & titlerow & ":A" & lr).EntireRow.Copy Sheets(myarr(i) &     "").Range("A1")
        Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Columns.AutoFit
    Next

    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    ws.Activate
End Sub
```

and then I thought I can reverse all COL variables with ROW and vice versa, and even swapping the arguments around. But the code doesnt run, here it is after I modded it:

```
Sub parse_data()
    Dim lr As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim vrow, i As Integer
    Dim irow As Long
    Dim myarr As Variant
    Dim title As String
    Dim titlecol As Integer

    vrow = 1
    Set ws = Sheets("109 (2)")
    lr = ws.Cells(vrow, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    title = "A1:J1"
    titlecol = ws.Range(title).Cells(1).Column
    irow = ws.Rows.Count
    ws.Cells(irow, 1) = "Unique"

    For i = 2 To lr
        On Error Resume Next
        If ws.Cells(vcol, i) <> "" And Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ws.Cells(vrow, i), ws.Rows(irow), 0) = 0 Then
            ws.Cells(irow, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(1) = ws.Cells(vrow, i)
        End If
    Next

    myarr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ws.Rows(irow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants))
    ws.Rows(irow).Clear

    For i = 2 To UBound(myarr)
        ws.Range(title).AutoFilter field:=vrow, Criteria1:=myarr(i) & ""
        If Not Evaluate("=ISREF('" & myarr(i) & "'!A1)") Then
            Sheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = myarr(i) & ""
        Else
            Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Move after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
        End If
        ws.Range("A" & titlecol & ":A" & lr).EntireColumn.Copy Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Range("A1")
        Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Columns.AutoFit
    Next

    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    ws.Activate
End Sub
```

Running it doesn't seem to have any effects at all. Any help for this solution or for the code? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work on a dynamic number of columns, based on what's in the sheet:

```
Sub a()

    Dim col As Object

    With Sheets("SheetName")
        For Each col In .UsedRange.Columns
            Sheets.Add
            ActiveSheet.Name = "Column" & col.Column
            col.Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1)
        Next col
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the input! :) However, your code did not work :( it showed the error "Out of Range"

Comment: Ah! My bad.. haha yes, I've just tried it and it worked! Thanks a bunch! I wish I could upvote your answer too but then I do not have enough rep at the moment :(

Answer (score 1):

Here's a piece of code that'll split columns to worksheets, assuming that the columns have a value in the first row.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Main()
    '---Variables---
    Dim source As Worksheet
    Dim column As Long
    Dim i As Long

    '---Customize---
    Set source = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1) 'The source sheet containing the data

    '---Logic---
    i = 1
    'Get the last column with a value in row 1
    column = source.Cells(1, source.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).column
    Do While i <= column
        If source.Cells(1, i).Value <> "" Then
            'Add the sheet
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = _
                "Column" & i
            'Copy the entire column to the new sheet
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Column" & i).Range("A1").EntireColumn.Value = _
                source.Cells(1, i).EntireColumn.Value
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply!
Yours has worked the best! However, is there any way to name all the worksheets according to the first cell of the column?
Referring back to my example, the name of the worksheets would be House1 and House2.

Comment: Sure, you need to tweak the two lines in the `If source.Cells(1, i).Value <> "" Then` though. Change the first one to `ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = source.Cells(1, i).Value` and the second to `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(source.Cells(1, i).Value).Range("A1").EntireColumn.Value = source.Cells(1, i).EntireColumn.Value`

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
Sub Kolumn()
    Dim s1 As Worksheet
    Set s1 = ActiveSheet
    Sheets.Add
    ActiveSheet.Name = "ColumnA"
    s1.Range("A:A").Copy Range("A1")
    Sheets.Add
    ActiveSheet.Name = "ColumnB"
    s1.Range("B:B").Copy Range("A1")
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the input.
I've tried it however it just created two new empty worksheets with the name ColumnA and ColumnB

Comment: Sorry if my question isn't that clear
My request was to copy each column's data and paste it into a new worksheet
However your code only create empty worksheets, and did not copy the data from the column
I can see from your code it does have the copy but, it just didnt work ><

Comment: **What is the name of the Sheet containing the source data??**